# How do I set up teams on MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to set up teams using commands and I don't know how. I'm on pocket edition and I haven't found any commands that work on my platform. I want 2 teams one named prisoners and another named correction officers.

PS I don't know much about commands so please don't answer with too complicated language

Comment: This is not the place to ask for quick fixes (even though at times they are given). It is expected that you put a little effort and research in a question. What have you tried so far? Do you know why the commands you tried didn't work for you?

Comment: This isn't a fix, the commands I found are not available in pocket edition and I did look it up but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is (and has never been) any way of doing this on MCPE/BE.
In *Java* edition it is possible with the Scoreboard teams.

The only way this is possible in MCPE is with commands.

Comment: So you're saying it is possible with commands? Can you explain how to do it and add the commands you use?

Comment: First: wow, I wrote that LATE last night, and must have been 1/2 asleep. I meant Addons. I DO suppose you COULD do something like teams with commands, but it would be hard. For example, there really isn’t any way to restrict PvP to certain players.

Comment: @TheWarHawk2005 you can't really do that with addons either, addons can't just run code they must use the JSON API